# How to install jBilling community edition on heroku and/or appfog

Tags: heroku, appfog

I am trying to install [jBilling community edition](http://www.jbilling.com/community) on heroku and/or appfog. I could not find any information on google on how to do this. I used the simple way to deploy the war file on heroku and that did not work. I am assuming there must be some configuration changes needed.

Before I venture into this I wanted to get a shout out and see if anyone has already done this successfully and has notes that s/he is willing to share with me.

Comment: Hey can you add some detail to help people solve your issue? What was "the simple way"? What specific steps did you take? When it didn't work, what happened? Were there any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jBilling has both installation guides (for [windows](http://www.jbilling.com/documentation/users/installation/windows) and for [mac/linux](http://www.jbilling.com/documentation/users/installation/mac-linux)) and a [Getting Started Guide](http://www.jbilling.com/documentation/users/getting-started/mediation) on their website that list each step and walk you through the process. Try starting with those.